# How to Forward All Website Directories to Root public_html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I current have an .htaccess file with these RewriteRules that work for a single subdirectory path:

```
RewriteRule ^C / [L]
RewriteRule ^D / [L]
```

domain.com/Cxyz--> domain.com
domain.com/Dxyz--> domain.com

I can't figure out how to 1) Make this generic so any character regardless of case used to start the subdirectory forwards to the root domain and 2) handle multiple lower subdirectories:

domain.com/Path1/Path2--> domain.com

I am sure this is easy, but I can't figure it out.  Any rules I write, if they resolve properly, never show the site properly as if the CSS files are not accessible.

Comment: Are we talking about real Directories? Your Rule would also rewire Files e.g. /Contact.html or /Custom/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need real Directories (exist on the Filesystem)
Just do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# exclude if the Path starts with lower case letter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?[a-z].*$
RewriteRule .* / [L]
```

Comment: This almost works for me if I remove the   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d line.  Unfortunately, as you pointed out I have a few lowercase real filename paths I want to preserve.  Can you change the bottom rule so its any path that starts with an upper case character instead of the wild card?

Comment: Final follow-up... what if the there are multiple folders i.e. domain.com/Abc/Xyz?